# How to create a floating dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

I would like to float the dropdown menu on other items.But below code  shows the dropdown menu but dropdown menu is under the items. I have used the z index but it not works fine for me . May be wrong execution of z index.

```
 <style type="text/css">
li.css3videos ul {display: none;}
li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
li:hover li {float: none;}

</style>

<div id="css3navigation" style="position:absolute;top:119px;">
<nav id="css3mainnav">        <ol>
<li class="css3videos"><a href="http://www.tolly2day.com/video/">Videos</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Trailers</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
```

Comment: for which element you have given z-index property??

Comment: Here is a fiddle to experiment with: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cGJ6K/

Comment: @MarcAudet i have used the same  method but the dropdown is below the other sections.

Comment: Whey you say "the other sections" I am no sure what you are referring to.  Please be more specific.  At the moment, I am not quite sure what problem you are concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like the problem you're having is that the drop-down menu, when dropped down (or open), is showing up behind the elements that are physically lower on the screen than the main menu. Is that right?

Make sure your menu parent ha both a position value as well as z-index value, and ALSO make sure the objects you want your menu to appear over the top of have position values too. You can assign z-indexes to them as well if you want to be thorough.